# How do I run two shell scripts in two terminal windows using Applescript?

Tags: applescript, window-management

I can't figure out the Applescript code to run two different shell scripts in two windows.

What I got so far is...

```
set s1 to "echo A"
set s2 to "echo A"
tell application "Terminal"
    activate
    tell window 0
        set visible to true
    end tell
    set shell to do script s1 in window 0
    tell window 1
        set visible to true
    end tell
    set shell to do script s2 in window 1
end tell
```

But this displays everything in one window. This is pissing me off, please help!

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't `do script` open a new window by default?

```
tell application "Terminal"
    activate
    do script "echo A"
    do script "echo A"
end tell
```